# Git bringing all commits from one repo to another

Tags: git

At work we had a GIT repository let's call it OriginalRepo with many folders. There was made a decision to provide to another team a new repository (Let's call NewRepo) with a few folders from OriginalRepo. The folder structure is the same in both repositories, the only difference is that NewRepo has a subset of folders. Another team has made 200+ commits with a few branches.

What we want is to bring all branches with all commits from NewRepo into OriginalRepo to the commit from which they diverged.
I would like all branches which were created in NewRepo to be called in OriginalRepo

"NewRepo_" + NewRepoBranchName

all commits I would like have same authors & dates. Is it possible to create a script doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess simplest way to do this would be to do (in OriginalRepo):

```
git remote add NewRepo <url-to-new-repo>
git fetch NewRepo
```

Now all remote refs will be stored in `.git/refs/remotes/NewRepo`.
In other words, you could do:

```
git checkout NewRepo/NewRepoBranchName
```

I think that should be enough.

---

If you want to create local branches corresponding to each remote branch in NewRepo, you could use a for loop like this:

```
#/bin/bash
for REMOTE_BRANCH in $(git branch -r | grep -o "[^ ]*" | grep "^NewRepo")  #Loop through all remote branches from NewRepo
do
    BRANCH=$(echo $REMOTE_BRANCH | grep -o -P "(?<=^NewRepo/).*") #Remove the NewRepo/ prefix
    LOCAL_BRANCH=NewRepo_$BRANCH #Add NewRep_ prefix
    git branch $LOCAL_BRANCH $REMOTE_BRANCH #Create local branch corresponding to the remote branch
done
```

Comment: Alderath, many thanks for the provided solution. Actually I wanted to have branches with all commits.
I have found cherry-pick is very good.
git cherry-pick sha1..shaN